High $R^2$ and sign. LOF for the descriptive purposes
I'm fitting my data using the Response Surface methodology. So, ideally, the relation between the response and independent variables should be described with the polynomial equation.
When I included all the coefficients, the $R^2$ adj. is good, but the lack of fit is significant. After reducing the model/adding parameters/transforming the data, I still can't achieve an absence of lack of fit with a good $R^2$ adj.
Can I still use the equation to describe the effect of my variables on the response, as the $R^2$ adj is big? So, I won't use it for predictive purposes, but just descriptive ones.

Welcome to Cross Validated! What do you mean that the adjusted $R^2$ is good yet there is still a lack of fit?

Thanks for the comment! The former is above 0.7, for example, but lack of fit p value is < .01.

How are you testing the lack of fit?

In such cases I would visualise the data to see what's going on.
